# Migrating shared folders to NAS

Tags: windows, network-shares, nas, links

We have 2 win 2k3 servers that store a good amount of files inside shared folders for all the departments in our organization. We want to migrate the shared folders to a new NAS appliance that we just bought.

Since we've been using this shared folders for years our users have thousands of files (excel, word, etc.) that have hyperlinks to other files located in these share.

What would be a good procedure to migrate our shares and don't break the links inside all the files contained in them? I'm also wondering if there is a tool that will automatically update the hyperlinks to point to the new location.

Comment: will the servers remain online with the same name after you move everything to the NAS? do you use a DNS server in addition to NBT naming?

Comment: The servers will be decommissioned. They are old hardware with an old OS. We have a DNS server, but all links are using regular windows names. Ex. \\server-1\finance\file.xls

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to name the NAS with one of the server names. put that same server name in DNS, and create a CNAME to it pointing to the other server name. UNC paths will attempt hostname lookup but will fall back to DNS, if not found (this may slow resolution down on the first resolve of the CNAME) so it should appear as though both your servers are online, and your links should work fine.

Comment: The NAS is already up with its own name. Just wondering. Can I point a DNS entry to a specific part of the NAS? What would happen ff there is a folder name `finance` in server one and another `finance` folder in server two?

Comment: not really, but if the NAS has 2 (or three) names, a single share named Finance should work with all your links. the only issue is if you have duplicate file names.